# Write Hex string in Socket Communication in android

Tags: java, android, sockets, socket.io

I am working on Socket connection. I am working on the client side.
I have gone through this discussion [Socket pass value as Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546853/socket-pass-value-as-hex). I need to send the String e.g(0x01 is a hex value and a String "Ravi") at the server they are expecting hexa value like 1 72 61 76 69. I tried of converting String Ravi to hexa value as String and appending "1" and try to convert to byte array. I am getting an exception that StringIndexOutOfBound exception.

update:

`public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 2)
                                 + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }

```
public String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%x", new BigInteger(arg.getBytes()));
}`
```

I used these two methods to convert the 1Ravi string to byte array but i am getting exception hexstringtobytearray method.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, including sample input. Note that you're not really trying to send it "in hex" - you're just trying to send bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
        Socket sock = new Socket("host", port);
    OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
    out.write(0);
String s = "ravi";
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
    out.write(bytes);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. I need to send in the form of bytes. I tried the Hex String to byte array. I am getting StringOutOfIndexBound Exception.

Comment: @RaviTejaN: Please show us the code you've tried. Clearly you're doing something wrong (otherwise you wouldn't get an exception), but we can't tell *what* you're doing wrong without seeing your code.

Comment: for iphone there we are using framebuffer to send the data through socket.But i don't know how to achieve this in android.

Comment: thanks Evgeniy for the help. My problem is solved. Thanks once again.