# Sending ASCII over android TCP socket

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, ascii

I am trying to send some data over TCP socket from android to a linux server. The commond/data should be in ASCII. I am using

```
out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

to write and read from socket. Now from below mentioned post I am confused that whether I am sending the data in ASCII or its in some other format. Do i have to use any other "Streeam writer" or "output Stream writer". or I have to convert my string to ASCII before sending it to socket. I have not tested it on server yet.Can any one shed light on it,.

[Socket pass value as Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546853/socket-pass-value-as-hex)

[Ascii on TCP socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773846/ascii-on-tcp-socket)

Answer (score 0):

The code as written will output the strings using the system default encoding. There is another constructor for the outputstreamwriter which allows you to explicitly specify the character set to be used for wire encoding of strings.

Comment: What will the default encoding in my case? Not getting your secound part can you please provide an example of constractor for outputstreamwriter?

Comment: The default encoding is "system dependent" and controllable with system properties. For good reason most people avoid this ambiguity and force writers to use "UTF-8" which is the literal string you provide as the second constructor parameter.

Comment: It means that "UTF-8" is ASCII and I should change my current approach, is that so?

Comment: No, utf8 is utf8 ascii is ascii. You should specify "US-ASCII" if you want that. Note that ascii is a proper subset of utf8.

Comment: can you share an example of sending ACII over TCP socket?